# Need a suggestion

Tags: sql

I want to make website for a school and because of that I need a suggestion. I'm trying to make a schedule table for each teacher would it be good to set them in one table or in different tables for each teacher(Note: Teachers can change the schedule from the site.)? The schedule table looks like this but in order to include the schedule of all teachers I wanted to add the ID column too.[image]

And the second question about chatting. In order to add the chatting function to my site, I've  opened a new table with name Chats. So the question is would it be good to open different tables for the chats or it would be good if I modify the Chats table each time new chatting called?

Comment: I suggest a normalized database.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: A separate table for each teacher?  No, never do that.  Adding a user to the system shouldn't require *modifying the database schema*.

Comment: Please don't ask two questions at once. In this case they are related but once you have the answer to the first question the second one may be unneccessary anyway.

Comment: And your question title is horrible. Think twice before posting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, if you have the same type of data, it should almost always(*) be stored in the same table.

So to answer your question more directly: you want to put all teacher's schedules in a single table. And then have a column in that table that identifies each row as being part of a specific teacher's schedule.

Again, the answer applies to the second question. All chats should go into a single `Chats` table. You would use a column to identify *a chat* (message) as being part of a conversation, as well as the participants.

(*) To further expand on the *almost always* above. The reason I said almost always and not just always is that there may be some cases when having two, or more, tables contain the same type of data would be a good idea. For instance, in the schedules example. You may want to keep all teacher's schedules data in the `Schedules` table but periodically move data older than a year out of that table into an `ArchivedSchedules` table. This second table may have pretty much the same structure as the `Schedules` table but separating the data this way would make sense because it would improve access performance.

Comment: Wouldn't the chats table cause any bugs if it become huge?

Comment: Large tables don't cause _bugs_. It may cause queries to run slow but that would be a different thing.

Comment: You can always archive old chats.